# IntelliJ error - could not open init generic class cache for initialization script

Tags: kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKIKi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjPZT.png)

I was trying to download IntelliJ and learn Kotlin, but i get a BUG error before i am starting, and i dont now what to do..

- I have try to delete the scipts folder, but it just make a new scipts folder, and say the same error. I have also reinstall IntelliJ, and thats give the same error.

Is der someone there can help me? :-)

Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init4.gradle' (C:\Users\username.gradle\caches\6.6.1\scripts\3yb5naxddghzghazzdf2vk0em).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

Answer (score 13):

As per the details in your error message, you can see that the root cause is a gradle error.

Gradle is likely using an unsupported version of the JVM in your case (e.g. I could reproduce the error in the latest IntelliJ 2021.3 version where gradle was using JVM 17 from my home path, while the IDE itself was using JDK 11.)   In the attached IntelliJ Preferences screen, note that the JVM used by Gradle is specified separately.

To fix the error, verify the JVM version being used by gradle and specify a JVM 11 version to gradle.

IntelliJ Gradle Preferences Screenshot:

[image: IntelliJ Gradle Preferences Screenshot]

Comment: I was getting this error in a pipeline, and knowing that a JDK version mismatch could fix it helped me to resolve my error as well (was using an image running 17 when the project requirements stated 11)

Answer (score 2):

You should set these options when you create your project [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXIzQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

For me this problem occurred when i was using wrong JDK file to build the project that is the Gradle JDK used was a normal SE JDK rather than one preferred by Android Studio so you follow the following steps to solve it.

1. Go to Settings (ctrl + alt + s)
2. Go to Build,Execution and Deployment
3. Then select Build Tools > Gradle
4. Change Gradle JDK to jbr-17 (the one i am using) you can prefer to choose options from Android studio Java Home or Default JDK

Answer (score 0):

Or, when creating a project, choose Java - Kotlin\JVM